# Which folklore beasts/creatures are representative solely of regret?

Tags: monsters

Are there any folklore monsters or creatures which exist mainly, or specifically, to embody the feeling of regret as it haunts people? I have been unable to find anything myself, although my knowledge in the world of folklore and mythology is somewhat lacking.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Greek goddess Oizys, she is the goddess of misery, grief and regret. Otherwise, the Algea were the personifications of sorrow in Greek mythology, daughters of the goddess of strife, Eris.

In African lore, we have the Tikoloshe or bogeyman as most western cultures adopt it.